# AJAX post using fancybox doesn't work

Tags: php, jquery, fancybox

my script:

```
$("#sl_selections").fancybox({
    'width'             : 370,
    'height'            : 480,
    'autoDimensions'    : false,//(width != '' || height != '' ? false : true),
    'autoScale'         : false,
    'showCloseButton'   : false,
    'titleShow'         : false,
    'padding'           : 0,
    'href'              : $('#itemInteractivity .copyMove a').attr('href'),
    'ajax'              : { data:  acao,type: 'post' }
});
```

in PHP return an empty post. Interesting if I make this:

```
$.ajax({
    type:           'post',
    cache:          false,
    url:            $('#itemInteractivity .copyMove a').attr('href'),
    data:           {data:  acao}
});
```

works fine, any idea?

Comment: Why won't you indent your code properly?

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but no acceptable answer.

Using Fancybox 2, I am able to get a post via AJAX to work with the following configuration:

```
$.fancybox.open({
    type: "ajax",
    ajax: {
        dataType: "html",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            "foo" : "bar",
            "foo2" : "test"
        }
    },
    href: "url-to-post-to.php"
})
```